# R: how to apply to a list a function that joins all subelements except the first one

Tags: r, list, function, apply

I am struggling with manipulating lists; now I want to join all subelements in an element EXCEPT THE FIRST ONE, in one operation if possible.

For example, I have a list that looks like this:

> [[1]] [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F"
>
> [[2]] [1] "A" "B" "C"
>
> [[3]] [1] "A" "B" "C" "D"
>
> [[4]] [1] "A" "B" "C" "D"
>
> [[5]] [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"

And I want to obtain this:

> [[1]] [1] "B;C;D;E;F"
>
> [[2]] [1] "B;C"
>
> [[3]] [1] "B;C;D"
>
> [[4]] [1] "B;C;D"
>
> [[5]] [1] "B;C;D;E"

So I need a function to apply in this way:

```
list2 <- lapply(list1,
                function(x) {
                  #something here
                })
```

It would be awesome if the function could be easily modified to leave out a different subelement (not just the first one, but the 3rd, or the last, or 2nd to last...).

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets make a reproducible example:

```
> L = list(LETTERS[1:6], LETTERS[1:3],LETTERS[1:4],LETTERS[1:4],LETTERS[1:5])
> L
[[1]]
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F"

[[2]]
[1] "A" "B" "C"

[[3]]
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"

[[4]]
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"

[[5]]
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"
```

Then you drop the first element and paste everything else together with a semicolon:

```
> lapply(L, function(x){paste(x[-1],collapse=";")})
[[1]]
[1] "B;C;D;E;F"

[[2]]
[1] "B;C"

[[3]]
[1] "B;C;D"

[[4]]
[1] "B;C;D"

[[5]]
[1] "B;C;D;E"
```

You get an empty string (no semicolons) if there's only one element in the list element to start with.

Read up about R's vector indexing to do selection of other elements of the `x` vector in the function.

Comment: Alright! this is exactly what I was trying now! what about if I want to leave out the last element?

Comment: @DaniCee suggest you read up on R's vector indexing - no sense repeating it here.

Comment: @DaniCee If the answer by Spacedman is the one that solves your problem, please, accept it instead of the incomplete one by Kota Mori for two reasons: (a) it signals other SO users to look for the correct answer and (b) it says thank you to Spacedman and and at the same time you're "tipping" (reputation points) - Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`[` is actually a function.  You can try the below.

```
list1 <- list(
  c("A", "B", "C"),
  c("D", "E", "F", "G")
)

# for leaving out the first element
lapply(list1, `[`, -1)


# for leaving out the last element
lapply(list1, function(a) a[-length(a)])


# for leaving various elements
Map(`[`, list1, -c(1, 2))
```

Comment: This answer doesn't paste the vector together with semicolons, as asked.